# Could not find metadata in local

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, artifactory

Locally on the machine i have an Artifactory installed with maven repositories, and i have a very simple .pom file for my project which points to it:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MYGROUP</groupId>
    <artifactId>NAME</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>VERSION</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>SRCFOLDER</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>TESTFOLDER</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-artifactory</id>
            <name>Artifactory</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>local-artifactory-plugins</id>
            <name>Artifactory Plugins</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MYGROUP</groupId>
        <artifactId>DEPENDENCY1</artifactId>
        <version>bla-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MYGROUP</groupId>
        <artifactId>DEPENDENCY2</artifactId>
        <version>bla-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

So i have local-artifactory repository declared with the intention that it will reload everything every time. Also i have couple of dependencies which are SNAPSHOTS.

Now i'm using maven 3.0.5, and when i'm compiling it it works fine, but it's not refreshing snapshots at all. Never. Ever. Log file looks like this:

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata MYGROUP:DEPENDENCY1:bla-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/opt/myuser/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Using connector WagonRepositoryConnector with priority 0 for http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/MYGROUP/DEPENDENCY1/bla-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/MYGROUP/DEPENDENCY1/bla-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (314 B at 13.9 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing resolution tracking file /opt/myuser/.m2/repository/MYGROUP/DEPENDENCY1/bla-SNAPSHOT/resolver-status.properties
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata MYGROUP:DEPENDENCY1:bla-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (/opt/myuser/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for MYGROUP:DEPENDENCY1:bla-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, already updated during this session.
```

So it constantly complains that it can't find local maven-medatada.xml and of course he's completely right - it's not there. And fails to do ANYTHING with it.

So i've tried to use dependency:purge-local-repository to purge local inventory and guess what? Apparently it can't purge it because there is no maven-metadata.xml in each artifact, what an amazing functionality!

Each .m2 artifact directory apart of .jar and .pom contains maven-metadata-local-artifactory.xml(with the correct copy of maven-metadata.xml from the artifactory, current), _mave.repositories and resolver-status.properties.

Maven is just out of the box, there is no configuration in .m2 and the configuration in the /conf folder is default without any single change.

UPDATE: I've just manually downloaded maven-metadata.xml from the artifactory and placed it as maven-metadata.xml inside .m2 for a dependency - no effect, it is still "missing" it. So i don't have any idea what it wants from me anymore. It just can't update dependencies because "already updated during this session". Well i don't know what it updated exactly, but apparently something else.

UPDATE2: Contents of maven-metadata.xml on the server:

```
<metadata>
    <groupId>MYGROUP</groupId> 
    <artifactId>DEPENDENCY1</artifactId> 
    <version>bla-SNAPSHOT</version> 
    <versioning>
        <snapshot>
            <buildNumber>1</buildNumber> 
        </snapshot>
        <lastUpdated>20130322155759</lastUpdated> 
    </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Comment: how do you put your artifacts in your artifactory ? are you using `mvn deploy` ?

Comment: No, i'm using ant/ivy and ivy:publish it using maven-style repository structure. Is it important?

Comment: I guess this why the metadata isn't there. I never use ant/ivy to deploy maven artifact on artifactory. Anyway: `mvn deploy` will put jar + metadata in artifactory and it's the way to go. (you may also use `mvn install:install-file` with the `-DpomFile=your-pom.xml` or the worst if you don't have pom file: `-DgeneratePom=true`

Comment: No, the pom is there in the artifactory, it's all fine there(that pom is generated by ivy as well). The problem here is that "**Could not find metadata MYGROUP:DEPENDENCY1:bla-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local** (/opt/myuser/.m2/repository)". It doesn't say it downloads .pom even, it just downloads maven-metadata.xml from the artifactory(successfully), apparently saves it as maven-metadata-local-artifactory.xml and complains that maven-metadata.xml is not in the LOCAL repository. Which doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: And if you mean that mvn deploy/install or whatever install metadata in local repository, then well it still doesn't make much sense because what if i'm deploy it to artifactory from the different machine? I still need to load it from the artifactory on the new machine without anything in local .m2 for it. And it downloads it fine, it just fails to update it. And for some reason it doesn't download maven-metadata.xml with it, which is maybe fine, but why then it complains about missing it???

Comment: Can you post the content of the maven-metadata.xml file?

Comment: Sure, i've updated my post with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the maven metadata xml file it looks like you are using non-unique snapshot in your repository. Maven 3 does not supports non-unique, only snapshot pom file with TIMESTAMP-BUILDNUMBER instead of SNAPSHOT. Do you have:

```
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/repo/MYGROUP/DEPENDENCY1/bla-SNAPSHOT/DEPENDENCY1-bla-XXXXX-Y.pom
```

file?

Comment: Hello@Eugene, Could you please post  how you solved this Issue. i am encountering with same Issue while trying to copy artifact using maven dependency plugin.

Comment: yeah - this is it. The bizarre approach actually from Maven. Thanks, friend

Answer (score 22):

My maven complained that it can not find metadata in local, blah blah... and basically, what happened is that i managed to unplug my power cable in mid-maven-build and its metadata in the relevant local .m2 subdirectory got corrupted. I went in, deleted the artifacts in question from from their .m2 location and re-tried the build. All worked fine. Just wanted to leave this message for those that have a similar problem to mine, but stumbled upon your question.

Comment: This is just a workaround, not a fix. You can't just delete the `.m2` folder a gazillion times to make the build work.

Comment: I don't think he's suggesting it as a regular fix

Comment: don't remove. Just rename folder and after move all packages to new generated .m2 directory